# Printing issue in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, printing

I am trying support printing my UI in IE, but am having issues (Chrome is fine).

This is how HTML looks like:

```
tr {
    height: 120px;
}
td div {
    height: 18px;
    width: 225px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
}
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row1
                            <div></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row2
                            <div></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row3
                            <div></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row4
                            <div></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row5
                            <div></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row6
                            <div></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row7
                            <div></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row8
                            <div></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row9
                            <div></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row10
                            <div></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row11
                            <div></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Row12
                            <div></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The above is also in JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/52Qn7/2/

http://jsfiddle.net/52Qn7/2/show

While printing this, prints in 2 pages which is fine, but the divs which has green color placed in "td" is not printing in the second page and pushed it into page 3 in IE, which obviously is not correct!

Here is the screenshot of the print out in IE:
[image]

Here is the how the print out should be as printed via Chrome:
[image]

Can you tell me what might be wrong?

**EDIT:**

I have two tables within a single table row. The other table prints fine. Everything will be printed fine, when i remove the **position: absolute** for "div" which has green color. But, my logic will broken when i remove that style.

Comment: The green lines arn't showing up in my print preview in IE :/

Comment: Please select the "Print Background Colors and Images" in print settings

Comment: You should really put all that styling into a css file. It would improve readability and reduce repeated code!